# Is it possible to make a condition in url rewrite rule that works only for part of users

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, arr

I have an ASP.NET site hosted on IIS.
I am using Application Request Routing proxy and url rewrite rules for some pages.

I add rewrite rule to proxy requests from http://example.com/my-url/ to http://other-server/my-url/.

```
<rule name="Reverse Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^my-url/.*" />       
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://other-server/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

The problem is that I want to implement condition that rewrites this page not for all users, but only for 10% or some other part of users.

For each user result of opening the page should be the same.

```
<rule name="Reverse Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^my-url/.*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="Is it possible to write a rule that works only for 10% users?"  />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://other-server/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You probably need a reverse proxy with more features than ARR.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to write hte logic in the codes to store some special data in the http cookie like "role=roleA", then you could try to write the url rewrite role accordign to the httpcookie condition.

Like below:

```
GET http://aaaaaaa.com/test.aspx HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: myserver.com
Cookie: role=roleA
```

Url rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Reverse Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^my-url/.*" />
<conditions>
   <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="rule=ruleA" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://other-server/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```